# scalacheck generator produces a null sample

Tags: scala, scalacheck

what is wrong?
why person is null?

```
import org.scalacheck.{Arbitrary, Properties, Gen, Prop}
import Gen._
import Prop._

case class Person(name: String) {}

object QuickCheckPerson extends Properties("Person") {
  property("gen1") = forAll { (person: Person) =>
    println("person: " + person)
    person.name == "john"   // nullPointerException, because person == null
  }

  val john = Person("john")
  implicit lazy val arbPerson: Arbitrary[Person] = Arbitrary(value(john))
}

QuickCheckPerson.check
```

It fails with NullPointerException.

However, the example works if I move the line `val john = Person("john")` just before `property("gen1") = ...`.

why??

**Update**

the example works if I declare the `val john` as `lazy`.
so, it seems that the `lazy val arbPerson` is executed before the `val john`, but if so,
the scala compilator should fail saying that `john` is not defined. `john` is a `val`, nor a `var`, so either it is declared and instantiated, or not.

any idea on this?

ps: scala 2.10.3

Answer (score 1):

> so, it seems that the lazy val arbPerson is executed before the val
>   john, but if so, the scala compilator should fail saying that john is
>   not defined. john is a val, nor a var, so either it is declared and
>   instantiated, or not.

No, this is not correct. `arbPerson` is a method internally, which performs double-checked lock and lazily initializes a private field. Since it is a method, it can be called from anywhere, including constructors. What you have here is essentially the following Java code (of course, it is not valid as it is written here, but it gives the basic idea):

```java
public class QuickCheckPerson extends Properties {

    private final Person john;
    private volatile Arbitrary<Person> arbPerson;

    public QuickCheckPerson() {
        super("Person");  // call superclass constructor
        // property field belongs to superclass
        property.update("gen1", forAll(new Function1<Person, Boolean>() {
                /* closure implementation */ 
            },
            /* implicit parameter converting boolean to Prop */,
            arbPerson(),
            /* other implicits */
        ));
        this.john = Person.apply("john");
    }

    public Arbitrary<Person> arbPerson() {
        // Perform double-checked lock over a bit field (not presented here)
        // and create arbPerson if needed
        // Let's pretend that the following is double-checked lock:
        if (arbPerson == null) {
            arbPerson = Arbitrary.apply(value(john));
        }
        return arbPerson;
    }

}
```

Nothing in JVM prevents you from calling a method from a constructor, and this is what happens here. `arbPerson()` method is called before `john` field is initialized (and by default all reference fields are nulls), so `null` is supplied to `value()` method. Hence your `NullPointerException`.

Please do tell if there are any mistakes in my expansion of Scala code (or edit the post directly), I will fix them.

Comment: thanks, that's a good explanation of what is happening. however, this seems to be a problem of transforming scala into java; as far as understood, a val should be a constant value, and here we have this is constant only after the java constructor. it seems like a shortcoming of using the jvm. if scala would not be using the jvm, this problem would not arise. is this correct? so the question is, is this a known issue and shortcoming of using the jvm? is it a bug in the scala compiler?

Comment: @DavidPortabella As far as I know, this is not a bug, this is behavior defined by the spec. I don't have any links to SLS, but I'm pretty sure that this is how constructors work in Scala. Recall that body of class in Scala is its constructor, all steps in which are executed sequentially. Then it should be perfectly logical - values of all fields "below" some line will be equal to null (more precisely, to default value) if they are accessed on this line.

Comment: Moreover, as far as I remember, if you initialize fields using immediate assignments in Java then these assigned values will be available in the constructor. So I guess this is a deliberate decision of Scala language designers.